# Objective C: Show Hidden Button After Download and Keep It

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsuserdefaults, nsdata

I am trying to make an app that downloads PDF files from URL with asynchronous connection using the `NSURLConnection` then save it locally on the app and open it on iBooks using the `UIDocumentInteractionController`

I already managed to do all the downloading, saving, and opening it to iBooks.
I have 10 "Download" buttons (shown) and 10 "View" buttons (hidden).
Now what i want to do is to show the "View" button after downloading, I have managed to that by setting the hidden property of the "View" button to NO after the download has finished.
It is under this delegate `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`

But what happens is whenever I terminate the app in the background and restarts the app it restores everything to its original. How will I able to do the result that I am trying to come up? I've heard of `NSUserDefaults` but I don't know how to use it, I'm quite a noob in Objective C.

Comment: -1 for not reducing your question to the real question, which is how to save status from one use of your app to the next.  Whether you're saving the status of a button or the user's favorite color is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSUserDefaults is a simple static dictionary you can access throughout your application. Here you'd want to set a key in your appDelegate after the download(s) is/are complete:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"finishedDownloads"];
```

You can then use that value to determine what to do with those buttons on application launch:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"finishedDownloads"] == TRUE)
{
    //show view buttons
} else {
    //show download buttons
}
```

Before doing that check you'd want to see if that key exists in the NSUserDefaults:

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"finishedDownloads"])
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey:@"finishedDownloads"];
```

This will simply make sure that there IS a key set before checking it's value. You can put this line in your `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching` method.

**In reference to this application specifically**

You can do something like this

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init...];

if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"finishedDownloads"] == TRUE)
{
    //show view buttons
    [vc createViewButtons];
} else {
    //show download buttons
    [vc createDownloadButtons];
}
```

Comment: Can I put the first line of code that you mentioned on the connectionDidFinish? Then the condition will be in appDelegate.m?

Comment: my buttons are declared programmatically in my ViewController file, how will I access it in the AppDelegate?

Comment: You can create two methods in your ViewController file to create the buttons instead of creating them initially then hiding them. You can create your view and call the appropriate method based on that conditional.

Comment: You can declare the NSUserDefaults change and create a `[vc removeDownloadButtons]` method in `connectionDidFinishLaunching`. The removeDownloadButtons method would, remove any download buttons on the  ViewControlle instance.